# App crashes when tapped frequently

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I am working on an app for iPad. In one class, I have used a scroll view at the bottom of the screen. This scroll view has some buttons. Those button play a video or open a PDF file. When user frequently taps on those button the app crashes. I have no idea why is it happening. Can any one please tell me why is it happening and how can I fix this crash?
Regards
PC

Comment: none can unless you provide us with: 1. source, 2. crash log and 3. stack trace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should track the state of your view.  Which button was pressed last, and don't allow it to be pressed again until.

a) it is done loading the pdf/video

and/or

b) another button has been pressed

You might have to be more strict than that, but we cannot help more than that at this point as Till mentions in your comments

Comment: This sounds right. You could do this by either disabling the button or keeping a boolean as a flag.